# Create a MXF media with a video and audio clip at specific timing compatible with Pro Tools

Tags: ffmpeg, timecode

I have several media:

- one video file
- several audio files

I would like to create a new MXF media with the video file and mixing the audio files at specific timestamp and tracks:

- Starting time of the video file on the track 0: `00:00:00:00`
- Starting time of the audio clip 1 on the track 1: `00:00:30:00`
- Starting time of the audio clip 2 on the track 2: `00:00:35:00`
- Starting time of the audio clip 3 on the track 2: `00:00:45:00`
- ...

I made a first try with just with one video and one audio. I used the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i picsou.mp4 \
  -itsoffset 2 \
  -i picsou.wav \
  -shortest \
  out.mp4
```

Unfortunately, when I import it in *Pro Tools*, I cannot see the audio.

Comment: Adapt the method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48169214/5726027

Comment: @Gyan when I look as the solution you propose, it seems that the `adelay` filter delay the full channel...

Comment: Share your command.

Comment: Ok the `-itsoffset` option solved my problem but change a little bit the subject to explain exactly what I want to do: a MXF file.

Comment: for *Pro Tools*

Answer (score 1):

The method in my comment still stands.

Let's say you have two audio tracks. Basic command syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i picsou.mp4 \
       -i audio1.wav \
       -i audio2.wav \
       - filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=30000|30000[1a];\
                         [2:a]adelay=35000|35000[2a]" \
      -map 0:v -map "[1a]" -map "[2a]" -c:v copy -shortest \
  out.mxf
```

The adelay filter here expects two channels per input stream. Channel delay values are in milliseconds.

On linux / OSX you may have to use single quotes around the arguments.

Comment: Pro Tools support MXF OPATOM, so you need to precise it with the following parameter `-f mxf_opatom`

Comment: Opatom only supports a single stream. In your Q, you state, "*I would like to create a new MXF media with the video file and mixing the audio files at specific timestamp and tracks:*" which can't be done with Op Atom.

Comment: Yes I know. I finally understood that MXF was a dead end and I will need to generate an OMF. I'll test your solution in order to generate a wav in the meantime!

Comment: Maybe I should update my question to go back to the audio pcm question if you don't mine?